# Where is the best place to ask an Arch Linux-related question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got this question that I wanted to ask regarding [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) problems, but [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) doesn't seem to be the right place to ask. Can someone advise me?

```
Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x27a cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

Comment: I feel like part of the question is missing...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We do have a [Unix and Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com) but you'd have to ask a clearer question than just posting the text you've quoted. Describe the problem, how it was caused and what you've done so far to try to fix it for example.

All sites also have [a help centre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), reading that before posting is a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

Well - there's likely more to the question you wanted to ask - but Super User covers questions on [computer hardware and software in general](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [Unix and Linux has a more specific scope](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) . Either would work here. That said, you probably need a little more detail to your question than what's given here.